# Partial derivative in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, derivative

Suppose *f(x)* is a neural network with weights *w*. If I do

```
loss = -f(f(x))  
loss.backward()
self.optim.step()
```

then this is the same as to go in the direction of *f'(f(x))df(x)/dw + df/dw(f(x))*. But if I want to ignore the second part and only move in the direction of *f'(f(x))df(x)/dw*, what would be a simple way to do it in PyTorch?

Comment: I suspect you don't really want to do this. Why do you think this is necessary?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy That's a part of the optimization problem I want to solve. I've presented only an example here to make is simpler. But mathematically the right gradient in my problem shouldn't contain df/dw(f(x))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, one possible solution is just to have a target network:

```
f_target.load_state_dict(f.state_dict())
f_target.eval()
loss = -f_target(f(x))
loss.backward()
self.optim.step()
```